# React-Native NativeBase onChangeText event for searchBar

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to trigger the event onChangeText on NativeBase for the Search Bar but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's what I have so far

The alert is not showing at all, should the onChangeText be working here?

```
_onChangeSearchText(text) {

    //do something

}


render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <Header searchBar rounded
          onChangeText={this._onChangeSearchText.bind(this)}
          autoCorrect={false}>
            <Item>
              <Icon name="ios-search" />
              <Input placeholder="Search" />
              <Icon name="ios-people" />
            </Item>
            <Button transparent>
              <Text>Search</Text>
            </Button>
          </Header>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Header` does not have any `onChangeText` prop. You have to pass `onChangeText` to `Input`.

```
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
          <Header searchBar rounded autoCorrect={false}>
            <Item>
              <Icon name="ios-search" />
              <Input
                onChangeText={this._onChangeSearchText.bind(this)} // <-- Here
                placeholder="Search"
              />
              <Icon name="ios-people" />
            </Item>
            <Button transparent>
              <Text>Search</Text>
            </Button>
          </Header>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to find what props are available for native base components in the docs. It just gives code examples. Do you know where they are?